# Pass port number into a response redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the next code for receiving elements from a form but the problem is that I want to use a specific port for retrieving the url. But when I type down the domain and the port as follow in the response redirect

```
Response.Redirect("http://mydomain:8888/MyApplication/default.aspx")
```

The response in the browser is: http://mydomain.com/MyApplication/default.aspx without the port number. So,does anyone know how to pass the port number into the url?

Best regards.

```
<script runat="server">

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

     Response.Redirect("MyApplication/default.aspx")

 End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that what you are passing to the response.redirect is really the url you think it is? The above code is clearly not the real code since it is missing `"` around the string so I'm wondering if you are passing in variables that may not be the value you think they are... I'd certainly expect the above to work personally though I may be wrong about that expectation...

Comment: I think you are simply missing a '/' before your url like '/MyApplication/default.aspx' and everything will start working as expected

Comment: sorry, I have added the ", I missed them

Answer (score 1):

The `Response.Redirect` is passing the url from qualification, and they correct the url if its not in the form of `http://server/path`

You can ether disable this qualification using the [`useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.usefullyqualifiedredirecturl.aspx), ether make a custom redirect.

So ether `UseFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl=false`, as MSDN says, ether just use this function for redirect:

```
public static void CustomRedirect(string url, bool endResponse)
{
    HttpResponse cResponce = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    cResponce.Clear();
    cResponce.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    cResponce.StatusCode = 302;
    cResponce.Status = "302 Temporarily Moved";
    cResponce.RedirectLocation = url;

    cResponce.Write("<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n");
    cResponce.Write("<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"" + url + "\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n");
    cResponce.Write("</body></html>\r\n");

    if (endResponse){
        cResponce.End();
    }
}
```

This function is a cut off version of the Redirect function of asp.net

Comment: I dont see how to implement it. How do I do it within my code?

Comment: @FranRod change this `Response.Redirect("http://mydomain:8888/MyApplication/default.aspx")` with this `CustomRedirect("http://mydomain:8888/MyApplication/default.aspx", true)`